# Secondary Facial Condition is not read when facial image is not detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, if-statement, face-detection

***functional:***

User will take a picture using a webcam. When the camera snaps an image, a check page will appear; this page informs the user to hold on while a check condition runs to detect if the image captured is able to detect any facial features and image.

Hence, if check condition is successful, it navigate the user to an option page to either retake the picture or navigate to a new page. Else, it will inform user to smile and navigate to a retake page where, user can only select the retake option to have the image retaken.

***What has been done:***

Have made use of a faceapp sdk: `facepp-sdk.min.js`, to create the facial detection. And to also create a check condition if face is detected, option page is shown else, retake page is shown.

***Issue:***

The check condition is not being called. Hence, at the end, no matter if the image taken has got facial features or the image is a blank image, the option page is always called. However, the detection is functional as if the facial image is detected, the console log is able to log the smile index, gender and approximate age, Else, if no facial image is detected, the console log returns empty.

Hence, what has gone worng? Help pls.

***Code: method call to check captured image***

```js
//Function call for face detection
function Send() {
  // Send Capture Image to Backend Server
  var canvasServer = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvasServer.getContext("2d");
  var imageDataURL = canvasServer.toDataURL('image/png');
  var smilesDetected = 0;


  //Send image to server  via ajax    
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("POST", "image.do", false);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/upload");
  ajax.send(imageDataURL);

  // Send Capture Image to Face Detection Webservice
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("start: " + Date());

    var binary = atob(canvasServer.toDataURL('image/jpeg').split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
      array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    var blobObject = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
      type: 'image/jpeg'
    });

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        //If API server connection is successful
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          string_result = xhr.responseText;
          //alert(xhr.responseText);
          if (string_result != "") {
            var ageArray = string_result.split("age");
            var genderArray = string_result.split("gender");
            var smileArray = string_result.split("smiling");

            var age = "";
            var gender = "";
            var smile = "";

            //To get face detection data from server    
            for (i = 0; i < smileArray.length; i++) {
              if (i > 0) {
                age = ageArray[i].substring(ageArray[i].indexOf("value") + 7, ageArray[i].indexOf("},"));
                age = $.trim(age);

                gender = genderArray[i].substring(genderArray[i].indexOf("value") + 8, genderArray[i].indexOf("},") - 1);
                gender = $.trim(gender);
                gender = gender.substring(1, gender.length - 1);

                smile = smileArray[i].substring(smileArray[i].indexOf("value") + 8, smileArray[i].indexOf("}"));
                smile = $.trim(smile);

                console.log("age: |" + age + "|");
                console.log("gender: |" + gender + "|");
                console.log("smile index: |" + smile + "|");

                // Save Face Detection Result to Backend Server
                if (parseFloat(smile) >= 50) {
                  ajax_detection("function.do", "formType=detection&gender=" + gender + "&age=" + age + "&smileIndex=" + smile + "&isSmile=true");

                  smilesDetected++;
                  console.log(smilesDetected);
                } else {
                  ajax_detection("function.do", "formType=detection&gender=" + gender + "&age=" + age + "&smileIndex=" + smile + "&isSmile=false");
                }
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.log('error');
          }
          //Conditional check for face detection

          if (smilesDetected > 2) {
            $('#check_face_page').fadeOut({
              duration: slideDuration,
              queue: false
            });
            $('#check_face_page').animate({
              'left': '1081px'
            }, {
              duration: slideDuration,
              easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
              queue: false
            });
            $('#camera_option_page').fadeIn({
              duration: slideDuration,
              queue: false
            });
            $('#camera_option_page').animate({
              'left': '0px'
            }, {
              duration: slideDuration,
              easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
              queue: false
            });
          } else {
            console.log("Not detected");

            $('#check_face_page').fadeOut({
              duration: slideDuration,
              queue: false
            });
            $('#check_face_page').animate({
              'left': '1081px'
            }, {
              duration: slideDuration,
              easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
              queue: false
            });
            $('#PleaseSmile_page').fadeIn({
              duration: slideDuration,
              queue: false
            });
            $('#PleaseSmile_page').animate({
              'left': '0px'
            }, {
              duration: slideDuration,
              easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
              queue: false,
              complete: function() {

                setTimeout(function() {
                  $('#PleaseSmile_page').fadeOut({
                    duration: slideDuration,
                    queue: false
                  });
                  $('#PleaseSmile_page').animate({
                    'left': '1081px'
                  }, {
                    duration: slideDuration,
                    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
                    queue: false,
                    complete: function() {
                      $('#Retake_Only_page').fadeIn({
                        duration: slideDuration,
                        queue: false
                      });
                      $('#Retake_Only_page').animate({
                        'left': '0px'
                      }, {
                        duration: slideDuration,
                        easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
                        queue: false
                      });
                    }
                  });
                }, 1300);
              }
            });
          }
          // Get Total Smile Index from Backend Server
          ajax_getTotalSmile("function.do", "formType=getTotalSmile");

          console.log("end: " + Date());
        }
        //IF API server is wrong and unable to connect: set error msg
        else {
          console.log('error');
          console.log("end: " + Date());
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://apius.faceplusplus.com/detection/detect?api_key=13a1ee809a13a500db53fc1bf87ed332&api_secret=kZRP6kOtRHE8-XMbwH4YNqxyoPjDz0CY', true);
    //xhr.open('POST', 'http:// apicn.faceplusplus.com/detection/detect?api_key=fd21f9e710d4304775ee0841fe533c13&api_secret=9N9gyhRReVCq5-KuAQ-EZK1cYHxQTdAe', true);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('img', blobObject);
    xhr.send(fd);
  }, 2000);
}
```

***Code: faceapp-sdk.js***

```js
(function() {
  var k = function(d, a) {
    return function() {
      return d.apply(a, arguments)
    }
  };
  this.FacePP = function() {
    function d(a, b, c) {
      var e, f, g, h, l = this;
      this.apiKey = a;
      this.apiSecret = b;
      null == c && (c = {});
      this.sessionCheck = k(this.sessionCheck, this);
      a = {
        apiURL: "https://apicn.faceplusplus.com/v2",
        sessionInterval: 500,
        requestTimeout: 1E4,
        ajaxAdapter: "FormData" in window ? "XMLHttpRequest" : "jQuery",
        concurrency: 2
      };
      for (e in a) null == c[e] && (c[e] = a[e]);
      this.apiURL = c.apiURL.replace(d.RE_TRIM, "");
      this.sessionInterval = c.sessionInterval;
      this.requestTimeout = c.requestTimeout;
      this.requestAdapter = d.adapter[c.ajaxAdapter];
      0 < (g = c.concurrency) && (f = [], h = function() {
        var a, b, c, e;
        0 < g && 0 < f.length && (--g, e = f.shift(), a = e[0], c = e[1], b = e[2], d.prototype.request.call(l, a, c, function(a, c) {
          ++g;
          setTimeout(h, 0);
          b(a, c)
        }))
      }, this.request = function(a, c, b) {
        f.push([a, c, b]);
        h()
      })
    }
    d.RE_TRIM = /^\/+|\/+$/g;
    d.prototype.request = function(a, b, c) {
      b.api_key = this.apiKey;
      b.api_secret = this.apiSecret;
      a = this.apiURL + "/" + a.replace(d.RE_TRIM, "");
      this.requestAdapter(a, b, {
          timeout: this.requestTimeout
        },
        c)
    };
    d.prototype.sessionCheck = function(a, b) {
      var c = this;
      this.request("info/get_session", {
        session_id: a
      }, function(e, f) {
        e ? b(e, f) : "FAILED" === f.status ? b(f.result.error_code || -1, f.result) : "INQUEUE" === f.status ? setTimeout(c.sessionCheck, c.sessionInterval, a, b) : b(null, f.result)
      })
    };
    d.prototype.requestAsync = function(a, b, c) {
      var e = this;
      b.async = "true";
      this.request(a, b, function(a, b) {
        a ? c(a, b) : setTimeout(e.sessionCheck, e.sessionInterval, b.session_id, c)
      })
    };
    d.adapter = {
      jQuery: function(a, b, c, e) {
        var f, g;
        g = 0;
        for (f in b) g +=
          b[f].length || 0;
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: a,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          crossDomain: !0,
          data: b,
          method: 1024 > g ? "GET" : "POST",
          timeout: c.timeout,
          error: function(a) {
            if (a = a.responseText) try {
              a = JSON.parse(a)
            } catch (b) {}
            e((null != a ? a.error_code : void 0) || -1, a)
          },
          success: function(a) {
            e(null, a)
          }
        })
      },
      XMLHttpRequest: function(a, b, c, e) {
        var f, g, d;
        f = !1;
        for (g in b)
          if (b[g] instanceof Blob) {
            f = !0;
            break
          }
        d = new XMLHttpRequest;
        d.onreadystatechange = function() {
          var a;
          if (4 === this.readyState) {
            this.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (a = this.responseText) try {
              a = JSON.parse(a)
            } catch (b) {}
            200 ===
              this.status ? e(null, a) : e(a.error_code || -1, a)
          }
        };
        "timeout" in d && (d.timeout = c.timeout);
        d.open("POST", a, !0);
        if (f) {
          a = new FormData;
          for (g in b) a.append(g, b[g]);
          d.send(a)
        } else {
          d.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          a = encodeURIComponent;
          c = [];
          for (g in b) c.push("" + a(g) + "=" + a(b[g]));
          d.send(c.join("&"))
        }
      }
    };
    return d
  }()
}).call(this);
```